# Right align columns in Listview

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like there to be a bit of space to the left of the first column where you can click and hold to select multiple Listview Items. In this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIfag.png) you can see an autogenerated "empty" column to the right of column 5. Is there a way to move that "empty" column to the left?

I don't want to align the Content itself or add another column. Both don't solve being able to select items from the left side.

Comment: set horizontal aligment to right

Comment: Do you want right align content of column? Or you want insert empty column at left?

Comment: Assumning View = Details: You can align the contents of all but the first column, which is always left-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like there to be a bit of space to the left of the first column where you can click and hold to select multiple Listview Items.

I don't really understand why this is necessary. You can just click in the cell in the first column and drag to the right. That will select multiple items across multiple columns.

If you wanted to do this, you could do it by adding a blank column in the first position with whatever width you desired. When adding items, add them to the second column, leaving your first column empty.

> In this picture you can see an autogenerated "empty" column to the right of column 5. Is there a way to move that "empty" column to the left?

That's not exactly what it is. It's just a dead area where there are no columns. So no, there is no way to move it to the left. Columns are inserted starting from the left-hand side.

…That is, unless you hack it by abusing Windows's right-to-left layout support for controls. Set the control's `RightToLeft` property to `Yes` and its `RightToLeftLayout` property to `True`. The columns will now be inserted from the right-hand side. This will likely have other undesired implications; you'll need to test thoroughly. And make sure that you *revert* it back to left-to-right layout mode on systems that normally use a right-to-left layout.

[image]

> I don't want to align the Content itself or add another column. Both don't solve being able to select items from the left side.

Yes, of course adding another column will do this. Either that or I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "[be] able to select items from the left side."

---

Now that I better understand what you are trying to do, my suggestion would be to *indent* the item in the first column by a certain amount. The ListView supports indentation, but it requires an ImageList to be attached to the control. Without an ImageList, it just ignores the indentation settings. But the ImageList doesn't have to actually contain any images if you aren't using icons. An empty "dummy" ImageList works just fine.

Here are the steps (the order doesn't really matter, and you can do this either visually in the designer or programmatically via code):

1. Create a ListView control.
2. Set the `View` property to Details.
3. Add some columns to the ListView.
4. Add a new ImageList to your form.
5. Set the ListView control's `SmallImageList` property to refer to that ImageList you just added.
6. Add some items to the ListView.
7. For *each* item, set its `IndentCount` property.

Setting the `IndentCount` to 1 is probably sufficient. It is actually measured in multiples of your ImageList's `ImageSize` property (which, since this is a small image list, will generally be 16×16, but can be larger with higher DPI settings). If you need more granular control over the indentation width, you can simply set the ImageList's `ImageSize` property to 1×1. Then the `IndentCount` will be measured in units of individual pixels.

Comment: `I don't really understand why this is necessary. You can just click in the cell in the first column and drag to the right` When i try that it just keeps the item i selected first and doesn't let me select more than one. The Listview i'm using has the settings View:Details and FullRowSelect:True. Does that play a role?

Comment: @drouning No, that doesn't matter. It works fine on my machine. I don't have a way to record what I see on my screen, but if I put the mouse cursor just to the left of the first item, I can click and drag to select multiple items. It works exactly the same way as Windows Explorer. It is admittedly a small click target, which is why most users do the multiple selection dance starting from the right-hand side or the bottom. I can't see a compelling reason for your application to behave differently. People who use this idiom are used to it. But now that I understand better, I'll update my answer